# store grid and it's child control in to database and retrieve it in another window

Tags: wpf, vb.net, grid, xmlserializer, datacontractserializer

i have main grid in window which hold all my data i want to store it in database and retrieve it in another window. my grid hold following control:

```
 <Grid Name="myGrid" Margin="0,1,0,-1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="360*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="153*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="739*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <MediaElement HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="587" Margin="24,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="797" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
        <Label Content="Dishes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="353,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" FontSize="16" Name = "Dishes" Height="30" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Content="Quantities" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="503,130,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" FontSize="16" Name="Quantities" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Content="Price" Height="30" HorizontalContentAlignment ="Center"  Margin="634,131,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" Name="Price" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Content="Totel Before Tax" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="324,487,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210" FontSize="20" MouseDoubleClick="Dishes_MouseDoubleClick" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Content="950" HorizontalContentAlignment ="Center"  Margin="629,487,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" FontSize="20" MouseDoubleClick="Dishes_MouseDoubleClick" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Content="Discount" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="324,529,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128" Height="35" FontSize="20" MouseDoubleClick="Dishes_MouseDoubleClick" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Content="10%" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  Margin="634,524,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" FontSize="20" MouseDoubleClick="Dishes_MouseDoubleClick" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Content="Tax" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="324,569,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" FontSize="20" MouseDoubleClick="Dishes_MouseDoubleClick" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Content="20%" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  Margin="634,566,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" FontSize="20" MouseDoubleClick="Dishes_MouseDoubleClick" Grid.Column="2"/>

        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="587" Margin="31,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="797" Source="Lighthouse.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown_1"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="114" Margin="490,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" Source="logo.png" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="2" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown_1"/>
        <Label Content="Advertisement" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.54,-0.363" Width="196" FontSize="20"/>
        <Label Content="Grand Total" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="324,606,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210" FontSize="20" MouseDoubleClick="Dishes_MouseDoubleClick" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Label Content="1045" HorizontalContentAlignment ="Center"  Margin="629,608,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="2"/>

        <Label Content="Kaju Kari" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  Margin="342,180,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="2" Tag="1" MouseDoubleClick="Label_MouseDoubleClick_1"/>
        <Label Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="511,177,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69" Height="30" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="2" Tag="100" MouseDoubleClick="Label_MouseDoubleClick_1"/>
        <Label Content="240" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="663,179,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="37" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="2" Tag="200" MouseDoubleClick="Label_MouseDoubleClick_1"/>
        <Label Content="Paneer Kadai" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="341,213,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="2" Tag="2"/>
        <Label Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="510,214,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69" Height="29" RenderTransformOrigin="0.652,0.586" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="2" Tag="101" MouseDoubleClick="Label_MouseDoubleClick_1"/>
        <Label Content="210" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="664,213,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="2" Tag="201" MouseDoubleClick="Label_MouseDoubleClick_1"/>
        <Label Content="Better Roti" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="340,249,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="2" Tag="3"/>
        <Label Content="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="510,248,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" Height="28" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="2" Tag="102" MouseDoubleClick="Label_MouseDoubleClick_1"/>
        <Label Content="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="665,248,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="2" Tag="202" MouseDoubleClick="Label_MouseDoubleClick_1"/>
        <Button Content="Write" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="647,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Name="btnWrite"/>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: What is exactly your question? What you've tried? Can't you just serialize Xaml in to a string and store it in a text field?

Comment: no i have to store grid in database because i give some property field to user so it can change in user interface at run time and i store it database so when ever screen load again user changes remain as it is.

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't directly answer your question, you *really* need to know this. In WPF, we never save UI elements. Instead, we create data type classes and data bind the class properties to the UI control properties. In this way, we can then save the *data*, rather than the UI elements. In this way, you could do something like this (assuming that you created a class with the relevant properties):

```
<Grid Name="myGrid" Margin="0,1,0,-1" DataContext="{Binding YourDataTypeProperty}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="360*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="153*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="739*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <MediaElement HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="587" Margin="24,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="797" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Dishes}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="353,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" FontSize="16" Name = "Dishes" Height="30" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Quantities}" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="503,130,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" FontSize="16" Name="Quantities" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Price}" Height="30" HorizontalContentAlignment ="Center"  Margin="634,131,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" Name="Price" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding TotalBeforeTax}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="324,487,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210" FontSize="20" MouseDoubleClick="Dishes_MouseDoubleClick" Grid.Column="2"/>
    ...
    <Button Content="Write" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="647,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Name="btnWrite"/>
</Grid>
```

Then, once you've re-loaded your data, you just set it into the `YourDataTypeProperty` property and the UI controls will automatically render the correct values from the data bound object. Please see the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for more information about data binding in WPF.